# Bittorrent KRPC - Why are node ID's half the size of an info_hash and use every character a-z?

Tags: bittorrent, dht, kademlia

This has seriously perplexed me.

The original Kademlia offers that 160bit hex like a sha1 should be used for obvious reasons:
When searching for peers relating to an infohash, you simple search nodeIDs as they should be equivalent to the same system as the sha1 infohash.

But reading this:
http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html

the id's are `abcdefghi0123456789` which is:
1) Half the size
2) Uses more characters then standard hex encoding.

So what am I missing?

Why are node id's like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the raw binary node_id in the examples printable,
it has cleverly been chosen to consist of only alphanumeric characters.
The node_id in the examples are actually: `abcdefghij0123456789`
As you can see there are 20 characters = 20 bytes = 160 bits as expected.

`abcdefghij0123456789` hex-encoded is: `0x6162636465666768696A30313233343536373839`

Comment: Ok, it is binary encoded. That's fine. But I thought node ID's represent infohashes. That when you search for an infohash, you're technically searching node id's for closeness with the infohash?

Comment: No, node ID's does not represent infohashes. What's happening is that peers announces their participation in a swarm, to the eight nodes/node_ids closest to the info_hash of that swarm. A node_id SHOULD be chosen randomly according to BEP5. Later that has been modified by BEP42, to make sybil attacks harder to do on the mlDHT.

Comment: [This video](http://engineering.bittorrent.com/2013/01/22/bittorrent-tech-talks-dht/) does a good job explaining the basics of the mlDHT. It's done by Arvid Norberg, the world's number one expert on BitTorrent DHT.

Comment: "binary encoded" is a bit of an oxymoron, it's about as unencoded as the data can get. whenever you see hex somewhere it's *encoded* either because it's meant to be human-friendly or because it's sent over some text-protocol

Comment: Guys! Thank you so much for your added input! It's hard to find resources on this topic