# Send DHT queries to "router.bittorrent.com" response garbled text

Tags: java, udp, bittorrent, dht

I read the DHT Protocol in [bep_0005](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) page.

But when I send a ping query or a find_node query, the server response a garbled text (both of *router.bittorrent.com:6881* or *dht.transmissionbt.com:6881*)

Here is the Java source code bellow

```
    public String ping(final String id) {
    System.out.println("Start ping:" + id);
    Bencode bencode = new Bencode();
    byte[] encoded = bencode.encode(new HashMap<Object, Object>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4225164001818744013L;

        {
            put("t", "tr");
            put("y", "q");
            put("q", "ping");
            put("a", new HashMap<Object, Object>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -6092073963971093460L;

                {
                    put("id", id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    byte[] result = client.send(new String(encoded, bencode.getCharset()));
    Map<String, Object> dict = bencode.decode(result, Type.DICTIONARY);
    System.out.println("Bdecoded Data:" + dict);
    return "";
}
```

**Send Packets**

ping Query = {"t":"aa", "y":"q", "q":"ping", "a":{"id":"abcdefghij0123456789"}}

bencoded = d1:ad2:id20:abcdefghij0123456789e1:q4:ping1:t2:aa1:y1:qe

**Acrodding to the bep_0005 protocol the response with be like:**

Response = {"t":"aa", "y":"r", "r": {"id":"mnopqrstuvwxyz123456"}}

bencoded = d1:rd2:id20:mnopqrstuvwxyz123456e1:t2:aa1:y1:re

**But my response is:**

Response = {ip=��P���, r={id=2�NisQ�J�)ͺ����F|�g}, t=tr, y=r}

bencoded = d2:ip6:��P���1:rd2:id20:2�NisQ�J�)ͺ����F|�ge1:t2:tr1:y1:re

Send udp part Java code is:

```
    public byte[] send(String sendData) {
    DatagramSocket client;
    try {
        client = new DatagramSocket();
        client.setSoTimeout(5000);
        byte[] sendBuffer;
        sendBuffer = sendData.getBytes();
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("router.bittorrent.com");
        int port = 6881;
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuffer, sendBuffer.length, addr, port);
        client.send(sendPacket);
        byte[] receiveBuf = new byte[512];
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveBuf, receiveBuf.length);
        client.receive(receivePacket);
        System.out.println("Client Source Data:" + Arrays.toString(receivePacket.getData()));
        String receiveData = new String(receivePacket.getData(), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Client String Data:" + receiveData);
        client.close();
        return receivePacket.getData();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

read the response in UTF-8 , but the iso-8859-1 is also a garbled text.

who can help me,thanks!

Comment: if you want to talk to the mainline dht you could use an [existing library](https://github.com/the8472/mldht). it also contains a prettyprinter for bencoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the server response a garbled text

No, the response is bencoded and contains raw binary data.
It CAN NOT be treated as text.

In BEP5, to make the raw binary node_id in the examples printable,
 it has cleverly been chosen to consist of only alphanumeric characters.
See:
[Bittorrent KRPC - Why are node ID's half the size of an info_hash and use every character a-z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143107/bittorrent-krpc-why-are-node-ids-half-the-size-of-an-info-hash-and-use-every/42143710#42143710)

The `ip` key is a extension explained in: [BEP42 - DHT Security extension](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0042.html)

The received response is fully valid.

```
TODO: Working Java code
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!    if the response cant not be treated as text,then how can i get response info? to get ip and id value?

Comment: Sorry! Can't help you with that. I don't java. Try add a [tag:java] tag to your question.

Comment: Also thank you very much. I've added java tag .Can you add your develop language code? is it hex decode is right?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043257/why-is-hashing-the-info-dict-turning-out-wrong

Answer (score 0):

> `Map<String, Object> dict = bencode.decode(result, Type.DICTIONARY);`

This gives you the decoded root dictionary of the message as `Map`. Within that you should find the `r` dictionary as another map and with in that map the `id` value. What type the id has will depend on the bedecoding library you are using.

If it is `ByteBuffer` or `byte[]` then you should have 20 bytes that you can hexencode (to 40 characters) if you need it to be human-readable. The DHT protocol deals in raw hashes, not hex values.

If it is a `String` then you will have to convert the string back into `byte[]` before hex-encoding it. That is only possible when the bdecoder used *ISO 8859-1* to decode because that charset is roundtrip-safe while utf-8 is not for arbitrary byte sequences.

Comment: thank you!  I want to know if i want to do something with the id value, is it necessary decode it to human-readable string? or i just use it in byte[]?

Comment: that obviously depends on what you want to do with it.